# Is sync needed to read values of private vars in run method in class implements Runnable interface?

Tags: java, synchronization, runnable

there!

I wrote this code.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
         Main main = new Main();
         main.start();
   }

   public void start() {

         Info info = new Info();
         info.setBirthDate(new Date());
         info.setFirstName("Name");

         Thread thread = new Thread(new Worker("Test", info));
         thread.start();
   }

   private class Info {
         private String firstName;
         private Date birthDate;

         public String getFirstName() {
                return firstName;
         }
         public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
                this.firstName = firstName;
         }
         public Date getBirthDate() {
                return birthDate;
         }
         public void setBirthDate(Date birthDate) {
                this.birthDate = birthDate;
         }
   }

   private class Worker implements Runnable {

         private String id;
         private Info info;

         public Worker(String id, Info info) {
                this.id = id;
                this.info = info;
         }

         @Override
         public void run() {
                System.out.println(id);

                System.out.println(info.getFirstName());
                System.out.println(info.getBirthDate().toString());
         }
       }
}
```

But i have problem with understanding of needs synchronization. 
It's good to access private field such as id and info (which was init in constructor) from run method performing in different thread?

Or i needed wrap all read operation to methods with synchronized or sync block?

Comment: You don't need synchronization here as only 1 thread is accessing the values (the main thread doesn't). You only start to need synchronization when there are 2 or more threads accessing *mutable* values.

Comment: Good, thanks! I had doubt because i thought that may be need synchronized code block to reset processor cache to both threads has access to same data in RAM.